# Не такой(,) как все

Tags: пунктуация

Купил занятный подарочный набор, состоящий из блокнота и ручки. Он называется "Записки сумасшедшего". И одна из надписей на этом блокноте гласит, что "я не такой как все". Именно так, без запятой.
Я сразу зафиксировал ошибку, а потом задумался: а может, здесь действительно не нужна запятая? Если это устойчивый оборот, а он достаточно устойчивый, то, может, она и не нужна.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, запятая нужна по общему правилу: обороты с союзом «как» выделяются запятыми, если в основной части предложения имеется указательное слово «такой».

Садись такой, как ты есть. Не принаряжайся. Б. Пастернак, Доктор Живаго. Такие, как ты, рождались во все эпохи кровавой истории наших планет. А. и Б. Стругацкие,

Может быть,у Вас появилось сомнение, потому что иногда "такой как" не  относится к орфограмме "сравнительный оборот". В некоторых случаях запятая ставится не перед словом «как», а перед словом «такой», тогда это действительно оборот, сочетание местоимения с союзом превращается в союз "такой как" :

1) если слова «такой как» соотносятся с предшествующим прилагательным: Погода дождливая, такая как осенью. Обстановка в этом доме была мрачная, такая как в старинных замках (НО: Погода такая, как осенью. Обстановка в этом доме была такая, как в старинных замках);

2) если слова «такие как» употребляются после обобщающего слова перед рядом однородных членов (после слов «такие как» двоеточие не требуется): Туристы посетили старинные города, такие как Суздаль, Владимир, Ростов Великий.

http://gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/58_722

Answer (score 3):

Запятая нужна, сравнительный оборот обособляется всегда при наличии указательных местоимений: так... как, такой... как.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая нужна, но повод для сомнений действительно есть. Если рассматривать указанное сочетание как называющее человека, а не характеризующее, практически как второе имя, то можно оформить и так: не-такой-как-все. Сравните в философии: вещь-в-себе, "вещь в себе".

Comment: Tat, у меня к вам вопрос. Вот Грамота.ру предлагает писать: "Погода дождливая, такая как осенью". Тогда получается: "Он обыкновенный, такой как все". Оборот приобретает самостоятельность, тогда можно написать: Он не такой как все. Погода не такая как осенью. И т.д. Вы считаете это правильным?

Comment: Видимо, эта позиция связана с пересмотром союзов. (Мы уже говорили о появлении союзов "а значит, а следовательно" и др.) "Так же как" с середины прошлого века сложный союз. В ПАС он назван союзным сочетанием и дополнен вариантом "такой же как": «Если союз «как» и указательные слова «так, такой» с частицей «же» оказываются рядом, то они МОГУТ сливаться в единое союзное сочетание». Ср.: Погода дождливая, такая же как осенью / Погода дождливая, такая как осенью. Явная аналогия.

Comment: Но не думаю, что вариант с запятой будет считаться ошибкой, поскольку строгого правила еще нет. А здесь составного союза нет: Погода не такая, как осенью.